# Save File From Data

Tags: php, gd

I saw two different postings here about saving a file from a stream, one of which was marked as a duplicate of the other, and neither seemed to answer this question in a way that worked for me.

Given an image that is already data (it was created by the GD library) then output as `$image` from the function that created it, how can it be saved as a file? I thought that `file_put_content()` would do it but apparently not as it gives an error.

```
$ImageName = "test.jpg";

$ImagePath = "/var/www/html/site.loc/$ImageName";
file_put_contents($ImagePath,$image);
```

`Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/site.loc/test.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/site.loc/common/functions.php on line 906`

Line 906, of course, is the `file_put_content()` line above.

It could be that this is actually correct and the permissions errors are not bogus as I thought so not asking for help with any permissions error if it is indeed the problem. However, any advice on whether or not I am using the `file_put_contect()` function correctly will be appreciated.

Comment: You do not have write permissions at /var/www/html/site.loc/
If you use Linux you can give the write  permission to  user www-data (apache2) to write in this directory 

`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/site.loc/`

Comment: Thank you. Yes Linux and Apache2 (long-time user of both) and www-data is already the owner. The permissions error, oddly, seem to be only on this one site as I see lots of Apache error.log entries with similar errors even though the site itself is working.

Comment: check the permission of directory , chick if the the group has a permission to write on this directory

Comment: If the problem persists, try giving 777 permission to write from all 'categories' with this comand `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/site.loc/`

Comment: Here on my development system, the folders are 755 and the files are 644 to match the live server. If I change them here, then when uploaded to the live server, the permissions upload with them and an ugly error happens so I can't change them. If I give myself ownership of all files and folders, then I can save changes but if www-data is the owner, I cannot even though I am an administrator and am part of the www-data group. That's long been a problem on all mt development systems and reading online I'm not the only one!

Comment: 755 Does not give permission to write to groups
, It must be changed in order for www-data to write to this directory

Comment: No other way? I don’t really want to be out of sync with the live server but on the other hand I don’t often upload entire folders so maybe I can get by with 775.

Comment: There is another way, but unfortunately it works with the same logic, which is adding yourself to the group to which the user belongs www-data, but in any case the user must be given the ability to write in the directory.

Comment: I also think permission 775 will solve the problem

Comment: I am already member of www-data with full read-write permissions.